# server.send(join.encode('utf-8')) gives me this error

Tags: python

I get this error when i connect on the client.

```
felix+
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\felix\Documents\CODE\Uno02\uno02_server.py", line 23, in <module>
    server.send(join.encode('utf-8'))
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

The client simply receives some information from the user, and connects to the server. I am not sure what I typed wrong
Client code:

```
import socket

server_ip = input("Enter the server IP: ")
client =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((server_ip,42069))
name = input("Please enter a username: ") 
client.send(name.encode())
while True:
    server_msg = client.recv(1024)
    print(server_msg.decode())
```

and server code:

```
name_list = []
ip_list = []
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(("127.0.0.1",42069))
server.listen()

while(True):

    (clientConnected, clientAddress) = server.accept()

    print("connection gained %s:%s"%(clientAddress[0], clientAddress[1]))

   

    clientdata = clientConnected.recv(1024)

    name = clientdata.decode()
    join = name + " joined"
    name_list.append(clientdata)
    ip_list.append(clientAddress[0])
    print(name+"+")
    server.send(join.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
server.send(join.encode('utf-8'))
```

by

```
clientConnected.send(join.encode('utf-8'))
```

check [Python TCP Communication](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) for further details